# What is the performance difference between rendering View vs rendering an HTML file in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

*Considering both containing same static content*, what is the difference between rendering a view VS a HTML file from an action in ASP.NET MVC?

**Background:** I have some static content such as about page which I'm rendering as `ActionResult` view. I can also keep them in some HTML files.

**Question:** Does it make any sense to port the static content from view files to HTML files? I believe it will save server from processing View engine tasks - which is the reason for port (correct me, if I'm wrong).

> **One more important question:** How do I handle `Viewbag.Title` thing? This is passed to `_Layout` from view file only?

Comment: use a profiler like mini-profiler http://miniprofiler.com/ and check for yourself.  it's impossible to know how different files will impact performance without knowing what's in said files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it won't be passed through the MVC pipeline if it's static html. But the real question is: what performance savings are you looking for? I'd imagine the differences to be trivial: low single digit ms to sub-ms.